# how to add ui-state-error to p:selectOneRadio on failure

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'd like to make sure a p:selectOneRadio is highlighted in some way when it is required, but nothing is selected. Currently, there will be a error message added to the top of the page, but no error class is added to any component. This makes it more difficult for users to be able to find the problem when there are a lot of inputs.

Edit: added additional info in example

Example

```
<div class="options-item r">
<fieldset class="default-radio">
    <legend for="default_radio_id" class="legend-txt">
        <span class="required c">*</span>#{msg['label.legend']}
    </legend>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="default_radio_id"
                  label="#{msg['label']}" required="true"
                  layout="custom"
                  value="#{bean.value.defaultIsFalse}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.option1']}"
                      itemValue="#{true}"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.option2']}"
                      itemValue="#{true}"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <h:panelGrid styleClass="some_class another_radio_class" columns="4">
        <p:radioButton id="opt1aa" for="default_radio_id" itemIndex="0"/>
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="txt" for="opt1aa"
                       value="#{msg['label.option1']}"/>

        <p:radioButton id="opt1bb" for="default_radio_id" itemIndex="1"/>
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="txt" for="opt1bb"
                       value="#{msg['label.option2']}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <!-- some other non relevant things? -->
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I'm using primefaces 3.5

Is there any way to make sure some kind of error class, such as 'ui-state-error', gets added to the select radio or is there some other pattern that is used to identify missing radio selections?

Edit2: added additional bean definition for solution

For those who don't know this is the kind of modification you'd need to make to the bean definition to get the solution working.

```
private UIInput radioButton;
public UIInput getRadioButton() {
    return radioButton;
}

public void setRadioButton(UIInput radioButton) {
    this.radioButton = radioButton;
}
```

Edit3: added comments on Edit2 and complete solution

It turns out that you don't need to define a UIInput in any preexisting backing bean for the binding to latch to. You'll only need to edit one of your existing beans if you need access to it from within the bean its self.

Solution:

```
<div class="options-item r">
<fieldset class="default-radio">
    <legend for="default_radio_id" class="legend-txt">
        <span class="required c">*</span>#{msg['label.legend']}
    </legend>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="default_radio_id" binding="#{anyUnusedBeanName}"
                  label="#{msg['label']}" required="true"
                  layout="custom"
                  value="#{bean.value.defaultIsFalse}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.option1']}"
                      itemValue="#{true}"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.option2']}"
                      itemValue="#{true}"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <h:panelGrid styleClass="some_class another_radio_class #{anyUnusedBeanName.valid ? '' : 'ui-state-error'}" columns="4">
        <p:radioButton id="opt1aa" for="default_radio_id" itemIndex="0"/>
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="txt" for="opt1aa"
                       value="#{msg['label.option1']}"/>

        <p:radioButton id="opt1bb" for="default_radio_id" itemIndex="1"/>
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="txt" for="opt1bb"
                       value="#{msg['label.option2']}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <!-- some other non relevant things? -->
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is incomplete. The `layout="custom"` without any definition of custom layout causes that nothing is been rendered. If you remove `layout="custom"` (or use `pageDirection`), then it works fine. The error style class is properly been added. Please post a real SSCCE instead of non-working code.

Comment: I'm new to prime faces and didn't know that the other component was related. I added some more info. Is there anything else that needs to be added so you can recreate/help?

Comment: Just make sure that anyone else can run the Facelets code by copypasting it into `<h:body>` of a completely blank template without any changes (except of stubbing self-explaining data, where necessary).

Comment: As per your edit, you do not need the `UIInput` property in bean at all. Why did you think that? I did not state that anywhere in my answer. My answer was complete as-is. Just remove that unnecessary `UIInput` property and use `binding="#{radioButton}"` instead of `binding="#{bean.radioButton}"`. You're also not using that anywhere else in your bean, right? It's thus pointless to bind it to the bean then.

Comment: Your right. I thought that you were using short hand and it was necessary to create an object for the binding to attach to before binding to it. Because of this I created the UIInput in a backing bean for the page.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, do you know how the binding created this way is scoped? Is there documentation other than "An el expression referring to a server side UIComponent instance in a backing bean."

Comment: They are created on every request but due to JSF view state, it behaves the same as view scope. Note that when you attempt to bind them to a bean, then the bean may not be in a broader scope than the request scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce it. It look like just a rendering bug of PrimeFaces; they forgot to set `ui-state-error` on `<p:radioButton>` in case the parent `<p:selectOneRadio>` failed validation. I recommend to [report](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) this issue to them, if not already done yet by someone else.

In the meanwhile, apart from rewriting and overriding the renderer, your best bet is to manually specify the style class as follows:

```
<p:selectOneRadio binding="#{defaultRadioId}" ... />
...
<p:radioButton ... styleClass="#{defaultRadioId.valid ? '' : 'ui-state-error'}" />
```

The trick here is to bind the component to the view so that it's elsewhere available as `UIInput` instance on which you can just check [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) property.

Finetune look'n'feel with CSS `.ui-radiobutton.ui-state-error {}` if necessary.

Comment: I was able to get the error class with the method you described.

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing this server side, your best bet is to get access to the corresponding `UIComponent` (either by binding, or by a [static method](http://www.jroller.com/mert/entry/how_to_find_a_uicomponent)). You can then cast it to a `UIInput` (if necessary), then call the [setValid()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#setValid%28boolean%29) method and pass it `false`.